# Change base currency on Magento live store

Tags: magento, live, currency, radix

I'm looking for a way to change the base currency without having to update thousands of product prices.
To my knowledge such an action is not supported from the backend alone it seems.
The situation is as follows:

EUR is our base currency and all our prices and postage rates are set in EUR of course.
We also support AUS, GBP, USD etc.

The problem is that our store is located in a country that does not use any of these currencies. Therefore it would be better for us to change the base currency to the one used
in our location so we can set product prices and postages in this currency so that they always remain accurate regardless of the up and downs of the currency market.

Can this be done without going through all the products manually and update the prices (or, for that matter use a spreadsheet import)?

Answer (score -1):

You could check out Product Base Currency, it's a commercial extension though: http://innoexts.com/promotion/product-base-currency/
It allows to set base price in a local currency for each product separately. It supports the following attributes: Price, Special Price, Tier Price, and Group Price and provides capability to import/export products in multiple base currencies.